# Extracting coordinates from a ListLinePlot

Tags: data, ocr

I used an iterative method to resolve equations, then i plotted the results using ListLinePlot.
Unfortunately, now I need to use some of the data that was plot.
I know the X-coordinate, and need to extract the Y one.

Using the list of data that I plot is not an option, knowing that I'm dealing with points that don't necessarily exist in my list.

Is there any function I can use?

Comment: If you can't use the list of plotted points, you can extract them and then [interpolate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html), which will give you Y and function of X.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this  example could be helpful

```
llp = ListLinePlot[
   Quantity[{0, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 11, 16, 20, 22}, "Centimeters"], 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic];
pts = Cases[llp, Line[x__] :> x, -1]
lp = ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True];
Grid[{{"Plot", "Replot"}, {llp, lp}}]
```

Extracted points: {{{1., 0.}, {2., 3.}, {3., 6.}, {4., 8.}, {5., 10.}, {6., 11.}, {7., 
   11.}, {8., 16.}, {9., 20.}, {10., 22.}}}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the list of data, that you plotted. You just need to `Select`  those. `(x, y)` pairs you are interested in.

For example:

```
Select[plotData, MemberQ[xValues, #[[1]] ]& ]
```

To obtain the plot data, you can use `Part` on the ListPlot.

```
plotData=ListPlot[data][[1]]
```